# ./node_modules/.bin/webpack -d doesnt run , says not recognised internal command

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, webpack

I am trying to set up a react environment using webpack , Npm and babel.

the command , 
`./node_modules/.bin/webpack -d`  always gives either ( "." not a internal command or path not found or "node_modules" not a internal command).

I checked the content of my directory , it does have the webpack folder under `node_modules/.bin/webpack/...`

I even tried it globally.  But that does not have the path `/.bin` , instead it has `node_modules/webpack`.

in `$PATH` variable i have `C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules`

Should i add additional path , but even after adding `npm\node_modules\webpack`  into `$PATH` variable that above command is working.

Please advice so i can kick start the development.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know about react.. But its clear that its path configuration error. So can you please post the Project Directory structure??

Comment: try ```npm i webpack -g```, ```npm install webpack --save-dev``` then in project folder run ```webpack init```, then ```webpack```

Comment: let me try , il post back

Comment: Thanks Ultro.   Finally it created bundle.js file.   So everytime i have to run this command to create bundle.js!